# Launching phpstorm / rubymine with root

Tags: java, debian, root

I have a problem with launching of phpstorm or rubymine, when I trying to start it with root rights.

OS, I've to use: Debian Jessie.

I have that error: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

When I launching it without sudo, I't works fine (except possibility to save files)

Maybe anyone know solution for that?

Comment: have you tried gksudo?

Comment: same error: Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem: xhost +